# write a sql query to get the highest scored student name from each college for the following schema

Tags: sql

write a sql query to get the highest scored student name from each college for the following schema:
**Marks (schema)**

```
 sid
    cid
    name
    s1
    s2
    s3
```

**College (Schema)**

```
cid
Name
```

Comment: No.  We are not here to do your homework for you.  Figure it out yourself, or you'll never learn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a demand to do their homework, and not a question.

Comment: @OP: It's not that you can't ask homework questions on SO. But you have to show some effort first, and then ask a specific question on where you're stuck. In its current form, your post comes across lazy and disrespectful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

I believe you can figure it out after you go through some basic tutorials and try executing some queries.